# how can I create a directive that resets value in dropdown?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have built a tabcontrol with a colors dropdown directive for each tab. I want to reset the dropdownvalue in all the tabs in one go. This is the directive:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="colors=' ' "></button>
```

How can I make it reset the colors value?

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/AasWSJzBWib4aRZuAoBv?p=preview

Comment: You want to reset the dropdownvalue in all the tabs using one button.Right?

Comment: yes with one button I want to reset the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your plunker a little bit by moving the script into a seperate js-file for readability.
I also moved the button inside the div in which your tabs are in so that it inherits the scope and shares the same controller.

Inside the TabCtrl I added a function which resets the colors property. You can do it either by setting the color to an empty string or deleting the color property. Choose what you prefer.

```
  $scope.resetColors = function () {
    for (i=0;i<$scope.tabs.length;i++) {
      delete $scope.tabs[i].color;
      //$scope.tabs[i].color = ""; --Optional instead of the above
    }
  }
```

Hopefully this solution works for you.

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/NLKVlMTPxSWV2vUwZdri

Comment: It works but I would expect the resetcolors function inside the directive definition?

Comment: That would be possible too... see http://plnkr.co/edit/NLKVlMTPxSWV2vUwZdri?p=preview . But since the button controls the content inside your tabs, I would not suggest to specify that function inside the directives controller since it does not control your directive. Putting the function inside your TableCtrl will also make your code more maintainable.

Comment: probably a save issue ;-) This one should be right: http://plnkr.co/edit/6idRwhZHsanDkblWjTuR?p=preview